# Missing fonts in QGIS after upgrading to macOS Sierra?

Tags: qgis, mac

I've created a handful of maps using the Iowan Old Style font. After upgrading my Mac to Sierra, it wasn't there any more. I opened Font Book and lo and behold it wasn't there either. After digging around, the font lies in the /Library/Fonts folder and is accessible to applications that must access the folder directly (Adobe products, DYMO Label printer, etc). It isn't however accessible to programs like Pages and QGIS.

I'm trying to figure out how to unhide that font which I've tried a variety of deleting and reinstalling and such. My question would be if anyone knows if there is a way to get QGIS to act like the Adobe programs and access the font folder directly (or however it does it).

I'm currently running QGIS 2.16.3.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about GIS but I know a bit about fonts on Mac-my understanding is that some fonts intended for system use, which Apple reserves the right to one day remove if it changes its plans, are hidden from applications that receive a list of fonts from the operating system. Apps like Office and Chrome that roll their own font code can access them. So short of getting it through a feature request, you may be a bit stuck.

If you want to use IOS in Pages, you can, incidentally–just write some text in it in Word or another app that loads it and then copy the text into Pages. I have a TextEdit document containing one line of text in all the secret macOS fonts (IOS, DIN, Seravek and so on) for just this reason.